# When source code does not changed, but selenium webdriver deos not return the element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working in selenium with python.
I used the code that worked, one hour ago, but now it returns me that

```
no such element: Unable to lacate element:...
```

The  same code worked maximum one hour ago.

Where is the problem? I checked the source code, but it still the same

Here is my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://moitane.ge/shop/5-gudvili/43-axali-xorci-da-xorcproduqti")
time.sleep(3)
#el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='style__ShopProductSubCategoryChip-sc-1bc3ssb-2 iKSeHs']")
el = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='style__CategoryItem-sc-8ncu0g-2 tZtCz']//span[text()='ახალი ხილი']")

time.sleep(3)
el.click()
time.sleep(5)
ell = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='main-layout']/div[5]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div")
```

It gives me error:

```
  NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='main-layout']/div[5]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div"}
      (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
```

Here is copied element:

`'<div class="style__ProductItemWrapper-nvyr2y-0 cbyRwl product-item-wrapper"><img class="style__ProductItemImage-nvyr2y-2 gfMqx product-image" src="https://static.moitane.ge/Moitane_files/093c2492-ccf3-4515-adcf-2f610a09e473_Thumb.jpeg" style="width: 166px; height: 132.8px; cursor: pointer;"><p class="style__ProductItemText-nvyr2y-3 ebZGDv" style="cursor: pointer; height: 40px;">ბანანი  (წონის) (იმპ) </p><div style="display: flex; margin-top: auto; width: 100%; align-items: flex-start;"><span class="style__ProductItemDesc-nvyr2y-4 cIkCnK" style="margin-left: auto;">1 კგ</span></div><div class="style__ProductItemActionsWrapper-nvyr2y-5 kQtpVm" style="cursor: pointer; position: relative;"><span class="style__ProductItemPrice-nvyr2y-6 hLsuWS"><span>4.10 ₾</span> </span><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; height: 100%; width: 50%;"></div><span class="style__ProductItemActionButton-nvyr2y-7 bieLnj"><i class="icon-plus" style="color: rgb(146, 146, 157);"></i></span></div></div>`'

Comment: Add HTML add your code add error, explain is that element present in DOM, or you need to wait for it?

Comment: Can you explain why I need to wait for?

Comment: In case that your web element is not loaded at same time as driver sees the DOM, you need to wait for the element. That could be your case. put thred.sleep(5000), befor calling the element, just to make sure that is not a problem. If it is use expected conditions.

Comment: 5000 sec, is it too long time?

Comment: in Java it is milisecond is pyton it is seconds, wait 5 seconds to 10 and let me know do you see the error.

Comment: Yes, still the error appears

Comment: Add your code, and add the HTML of the page, so I can hepl.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: Great, seems that you have wrong xpath, can you also copy part of HTML code that includes last element where error ocures.

Comment: It is intresting, I can find element //*[@id='main-layout']/div[5]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div, but I cant find element //li[@class='style__CategoryItem-sc-8ncu0g-2 tZtCz']//span[text()='ახალი ხილი']
are you sure that it clicked on this element wit class name

Comment: Yes, this one '//li[@class='style__CategoryItem-sc-8ncu0g-2 tZtCz']//span[text()='ახალი ხილი']' works, but //*[@id='main-layout']/div[5]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div this one gives me error

Comment: I see now, nothing will happen when you click there, you need to click on image.
This is your xpath "//body/div[@id='__next']/div[@id='main-layout']/div[5]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/img[1]"

Comment: I added html element  of //*[@id='main-layout']/div[5]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div

Comment: This code worked several hours ago

Comment: The path you provided gives me the same error

Comment: I can not find your first element. But second one should work even you dont click enywher. Please see https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html and implement it as expected condition

Comment: This one also does not work, Is it possible that in comp is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of child divs will always change and you'll have to manually edit them in code.
Instead try shortened xpaths, like these:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'ProductItemWrapper') and contains(.,'ბანანი')]
```

where contains(@text, 'text') and contains(**.**,'text') are the same.

or if you just want first element add [1]

```
//div[contains(@class, 'ProductItemWrapper')][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to use webdriver-manager package:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

the code should look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

The module download driver automatically and store it at known path for selenium. It will solve all of kinda troubles with driver path what might appear in the future.

Second, please, provide screenshot of the element what you're trying to click with arrow, accurately highlighting it

Third, don't use absolute path for the elements, better relative, due to possible future changes in DOM and hard relation what provides absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Try using webdriver waits instead of sleeps:

```
# Wait for initialize, in seconds
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

ell = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((BBy.XPATH, "//*[@id='main-layout']/div[5]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div")))
```

You should also work on choosing better (meaning less fragile) locators. In this case you could use something like this:

```
//div[contains(@class,'product-item-wrapper')]
```